# query to remove all characters after last comma in string

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a mysql table with this sort of data

```
TACOMA, Washington, 98477
```

Now i have thousands of such rows. I want the data to be manipulated in such a manner that it appears like:

```
TACOMA, Washington
```

Is it possible though mysql or do i have to manually do it.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use :

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('TACOMA, Washington, 98477', ',', 2)
```

You can read more [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index).

And the update statement :

```
UPDATE my_table
    SET my_col = SUBSTRING_INDEX(my_col, ',', 2)
```

Where you need to replace `my_table` with your table name and `my_col` with the column you need to be updated.

Comment: and how do i do a update on the same column with new results in this query?

Comment: @AakilFernandes 2 is the number of occurrences ... you can read more here : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index

Answer (score 9):

Possibly this way. Count the number of commas (by checking the length against the length with all the commas removed) and then use SUBSTRING_INDEX to get the string up to the number of commas:-

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(col, ',', LENGTH(col) - LENGTH(REPLACE(col, ',', '')))
FROM SomeTable
```

Answer (score 6):

```
substring_index(col, ',',-1)
```

will give the string from last index of comma to end of string

```
replace(col,concat(',',substring_index(col, ',',-1)),'')
```

Comment: You're query returns `98477`.