# Remove all characters from a string after coma if comma exists

Tags: sql, oracle

I am getting the mobile number of employee from the table.

The problem is there are one or more numbers are saved in one column separated with comma, and I want to get only first mobile number.

Also mobile number has hyphen `-` sign , I also want to remove it .

For example :

```
0300-123766, 0312-8789709
```

I want the output to be :

```
0300123766
```

My code is working fine for more than one mobile number but there is a possibility that the column has only one mobile number .

I've tried the following code :

```
SELECT 
    mobile_tel,
    replace(substr(mobile_tel, 1, instr(mobile_tel, ',') -1), '-', '')
FROM tbl;
```

but this is only working when string has a comma, otherwise it's returning null.

How can I solve this?

Kindly help

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17421448/query-to-remove-all-characters-after-last-comma-in-string

Comment: no this is different from this question because here i asked to check whether the string contains commaa or not,if it dosn't have comma , it won't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `case` expression to do this.

```
SELECT mobile_tel,
       case when instr(mobile_tel, ',') > 0
            then replace(substr(mobile_tel, 1, instr(mobile_tel, ',') -1),'-','')
            else replace(mobile_tel,'-','')
       end
FROM tbl
```

One more way to get the substring upto the *first* comma in the string using `regexp_substr`.

```
select mobile_tel, 
replace(regexp_substr(mobile_tel,'(^[^,]+),?',1,1,null,1),'-','')
from tbl
```

Answer (score 0):

This trick would make your query work: `mobile_tel || ','`

---

```
SELECT 
    mobile_tel,
    replace(substr(mobile_tel, 1, instr(mobile_tel || ',' , ',') -1), '-', '')
FROM tbl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this query, I am sure it will get the result as you are expecting -

I have used the table name - **numbers**
Column names - **id, phone**

```
SELECT id,
  CASE WHEN phone REGEXP ',' THEN replace(substr(phone, 1, instr(phone, ',') -1),'-','') ELSE replace(substr(phone, 1, phone),'-','') END
FROM numbers UNION SELECT id, replace(substr(phone, 1, phone),'-','') FROM numbers WHERE phone NOT REGEXP ',' ORDER BY id
```