# Removing part of string after specific character using mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to remove the all part of characters after the specific character in mysql column. But i need that mentioned removable character. I have searched but everything the mentioned characters also removed.

**For Example:**

```
Tracding Company Pvt Ltd. - Welecome Home
```

**Need output:**

```
Tracding Company Pvt Ltd.
```

If i use `Ltd.` with `substring_index` then the `ltd.` also removed.

Please someone help with this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server replace, remove all after certain character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668014/sql-server-replace-remove-all-after-certain-character)

Comment: @Vakili, But if i use CHARINDEX functioon, its shows the following error, " FUNCTION CHARINDEX does not exist". Also, If use the certain character that character no need o remove.

Comment: Sorry, `CHARINDEX` function is used in `MSSQL`, you can refer to this question for MySQL: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17421448/query-to-remove-all-characters-after-last-comma-in-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17421448/query-to-remove-all-characters-after-last-comma-in-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just increase the index by the length of the substring you search, in your example 'Ltd.' is 4:

```
SELECT LEFT('Tracding Company Pvt Ltd. - Welecome Home', INSTR ('Tracding Company Pvt Ltd. - Welecome Home', 'Ltd.') + 4)
```

Another option is to use the [CONCAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function to add the missing value back:

```
SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX('Tracding Company Pvt Ltd. - Welecome Home', 'Ltd.', 1), 'Ltd.')
```

EDIT: Corrected based on comments

Comment: Instead of `4` you could use `length('Ltd.')` in case the search string is a variable.

Comment: @adambg, I am getting the result as only  "4" but i need "Tracding Company Pvt Ltd."

Comment: Fixed the answer to better reflect the question